# Port forwarding 3389 into local network safety

Tags: linux, centos, port-forwarding, port, rdp

I've installed xrdp on a system running centOS7 - this allows me to rdp from any pc on the network using the local ip/hostname. I'm looking to be able to rdp straight into the system from outside of the local network using my public ip. Port forwarding 3389 works. I've tested this and this is exactly what I want. However, I've closed the port for now and am now researhcing the safety of having the port open all of the time.

Is having port 3389 permantently open to the local network dangerous and how can I put other systems in place to make sure it's not found at random and brute forced - OR, attacked in any other way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether you've got authorization or not. If you have it I see no issues leaving the port wide open. If not I can see these two options:

- Encapsulate traffic into something only you can access. This could be VPN or SSH port forwarding. In both cases there's no need to open the port to the WWW.
- [Use](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Port_knocking) TCP port knocking [daemon](https://github.com/jvinet/knock). It's a kind of security through obscurity but it's near impossible to guess, so you may as well use it.